# How can I find musicologists' analysis of individual Modernist pieces online?

Tags: reference-request

How can I find musicologists' analyses that focuses on a single piece? I know they're probably pay-walled. [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=xenakis+metastasis&btnG=) yields nothing for Xenakis's *Metastasis* (1957).

To wit, I'm seeking articles for Xenakis's compositions like

- Alegant, Brian. “A Model for the Pitch Structure of Webern's Op. 23 No. 1, ‘Das Dunkle Herz.’” Music Theory Spectrum, vol. 13, no. 2, 1991, pp. 127–146. JSTOR, www.jstor.org/stable/745895.
- Alegant, Brian. “Unveiling Schoenberg's Op. 33b.” Music Theory Spectrum, vol. 18, no. 2, 1996, pp. 143–166. JSTOR, www.jstor.org/stable/746022.
- Ilias Chrissochoidis, C Mitsakis, S Houliaras. [*Set theory in Xenakis' EONTA*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254438279_Set_theory_in_Xenakis%27_EONTA).

Comment: This is the kind of research where a good library still beats the Internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allowing you're still looking for an answer...

There's an article on *Metastasis* specifically, in French, on JSTOR:

Anne-Sylvie Barthel-Calvet. "MÉTASTASSIS-Analyse: Un Texte Inédit De Iannis Xenakis Sur Metastasis." Revue De Musicologie 89, no. 1 (2003): 129-87. Accessed July 11, 2020. [www.jstor.org/stable/4494838](http://www.jstor.org/stable/4494838).

JSTOR is a good place to search. The journal *Perspectives of New Music* might be of particular interest as the kind of analyses you're looking for are a primary focus. There are many articles on Xenakis as well as other composers and compositions.

When I'm looking for analyses, most often I search through the bibliographies of articles mentioning the composer or piece.